# Unable to convert json date '1453204346' to 'dd-MM-yyyyy' format

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net, json-deserialization

Actually I have deserialize this json code:

```
{
   "id": "evt_17Uy2AJAW1ypyOFKd72w0Z6Q",
   "object": "event",
   "api_version": "2015-10-16",
   "created": 1453204346,
   "pending_webhooks": 1,
   "request": "req_7kSy7UdDi03tB9",
   "type": "invoice.payment_succeeded"
}
```

By this VB code:

```
<Serializable>
Public Class StripeHookResponse
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property [Object] As String
    Public Property api_version As String
    Public Property created As Integer
    Public Property pending_webhooks As Integer
    Public Property request As String
    Public Property type As String
End Class

Dim stripeResponse As StripeHookResponse = 
                 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of StripeHookResponse)(str)
```

But `stripeResponse.created` give the same value `1453204346`. Please covert it in `dd-MM-yyyy` format using VB.NET code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Unix Epoch Time to format HH:MM:SS without the date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741650/convert-unix-epoch-time-to-format-hhmmss-without-the-date)

Comment: Do you want your question to look misaligned?

Comment: thanks vikas pandey, i have updated my question please help me

Comment: thanks luis can you help me

Comment: praveen kumar can you help me

Comment: Hi "1453204346" <-- this come from ????? , by the way  this number has any meaning , something like first 4 numbers are YYYY

Comment: Thanks @Vikash Pandey, your "epoch time" hint give me way to solve this problem. I have answer it below.

Answer (score 0):

**Hopefully this sample code can help you  as following**
Try this; bear in mind that JavaScript months are 0-indexed, whilst days are 1-indexed.

**Front end with Javascript**

```
 <script>
             var date = new Date('2010-10-11T00:00:00+05:30');    
             alert(date.getDate() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +  date.getFullYear());    
 </script>
```

**Back end with VB.NET**

```
 Dim thisDate1 As Date = #6/10/2011#
 Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".")

 Dim thisDate2 As New DateTimeOffset(2011, 6, 10, 15, 24, 16, TimeSpan.Zero)
 Console.WriteLine("The current date and time: {0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz}", 
                   thisDate2) 
' The example displays the following output:
'    Today is June 10, 2011.
'    The current date and time: 06/10/11 15:24:16 +00:00
```

**By the you want**

```
 Dim inp As String = "1204262016" Dim dt As DateTime =
 DateTime.ParseExact(inp, "yyMMddHHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

> PS: you need to "Imports System.Globalization"

Comment: thanks willie, can you do it in vb.net as i am cannot use your code in vb.net

Comment: hopefully it is okay for you

Comment: thanks willie, i have updated my question please help me

Comment: I have added new code for you want , please check it again ,thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
Public Shared Function UnixTimeStampToDateTime(ByVal unixTimeStamp As Double) As Date
    ' Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
    Dim dtDateTime As New Date(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc)
    dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime()
    Return dtDateTime
End Function

dim req_date = UnixTimeStampToDateTime(stripeResponse.created)
```

it will give answer
    i.e  19-01-2016 5:22:26 PM

Comment: Please learn how to format your answers. Also a code dump with no explanation is not useful to people, please explain it.

Comment: Learn how to answer, and format the answers or questions. Do you understand English? Or Tamil la sollanuma? Telugu lo cheppalana? Mein Hindi mein bata dena chaahie?